# Apache 2.2.3, DISABLE redirect port 80 to 443

Tags: apache-2.2, port

Sorry if I'm not clear, 
I'm newbie...

We have a server Apache 2.2.3 on RHEL.
In the httpd.conf there is no VirtualHost configuration,
And the iptables service is stopped

Based on this, 
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL
I added in the httpd.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mysite.address.com

</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to access http://mysite.address.com
I still get https://mysite.address.com

(Thanks Simon Greenwood)
There is a .htaccess with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It seems for me that

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

redirect *all* to *https*
Isn't it?

If yes, is it enouth to comment this line to stop the redirect?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` file in the web root? It's most likely to be in there.

Comment: Look in your httpd.conf file for "Include" directive and then check what do you have in files in this directories. And remember, if you have once opened your website in web browser with "https" it's remember that and will be automatically try to open it via https, so the best way is to check if it works as should is to use "curl -I" (bigger i) in terminal (or clear cache and rests settings for this site, restart web browser and check).

Comment: Are you trying with a browser? Perhaps the redirect is cached. Have you tried curl?

Comment: If HSTS was enabled, that would most definitely conflict with this issue. As mentioned many times, make sure to test with `curl`. Also, it's important that the `httpd` service was **restarted** after changing the configuration.

Comment: Yes, there is .htaccess file and test the site in incognito mode on different tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove RewriteRule for `https` and this prevent redirect from `http` to `https`. Also, you could remove whole `.htaccess` file, it doesn't contain anything except rewriting to `https`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, (I cannot remove it. it s just a part of it.)

Comment: Where is https rule, I want to remove it, but can find no where. I could only see this line in .htaccess `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` I removed and it makes no difference

Comment: @Sami you should read [how 301 redirect works](https://www.seoclarity.net/resources/knowledgebase/use-301-redirect-vs-302-redirect-15683/).